# How to use variables as list indices?

Tags: python, list, indices

I have some nested list whose items can be accessed normally with:

```
list[0][2]
```

However, when I try to use a variable instead:

```
uinput = input("Number: )
list[uinput][2]
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

(I have tried it with a dictionary using the same format and it threw the same error)

Comment: don't call your lists `list`

Comment: I tend to be more descriptive but this was just an example. Is list reserved somewhere in python or is it for readability you suggest not to?

Comment: If you use list as the name of a variable, you will no longer be able to construct lists using the list(...) builtin function (because you overwrote the name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing it right but you have to convert it to integer first.

```
uinput = int(input('Number: '))
```

Otherwise it's a string and will throw the error you saw.

Comment: Perfect and only 60 seconds from asking too

Comment: You were already very close to a solution!